# wpf/silverlight application to dvd

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How to convert a wpf/silverlight app so it will run on a dvd.
We have wpf app which is used for learning purposes we would like to create dvd version of this app and give it to our users so they could go home and use them.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
We have looked at WPFMediaKit but it appears to be opening media files and displaying them.
But our requirement is to actually play the wpf app on dvd just like a normal dvd. 
Just wondering if it is possible.
Thanks
N

Comment: Also, you shouldn't open a new question if you want more answers on your original question - just edit that original question or comment on any answers on there to help people understand why their current answers aren't helping you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wpf app on dvd how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858873/wpf-app-on-dvd-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible. DVD navigation (on which interactive DVDs are built) are a *completely* different environment / framework / format to WPF or Silverlight.

WPF/Silverlight use XAML and the .Net framework, the DVD format uses a combination of motion menus and navigation controls to achieve interaction, all packaged in a format unique to DVDs and as different to WPF/Silverlight as oil is to cheese I'm afraid.

If, however, you want to distribute your WPF/Silverlight application on a data DVD for users to insert into their Windows PCs and run on their desktop, that will be very easy.

---

DVD-Video players run a special virtual machine to run byte-code specifying how the navigation of a DVD-video disc should work. [This site](http://www.dvd-replica.com/DVD/productinfo.php) gives a detailed account of this format and how to program for it.

The bottom line is that if you want your WPF/Silverlight app to run on a DVD-Video disc on a consumer DVD-player, not on a Windows PC, you will need to completely rewrite it from scratch using this format.

Comment: I don't think np meant a DVD-video, just a standard data one the user can put in a pc to launch the app.

Comment: That's not how I read it: "But our requirement is to actually play the wpf app on dvd just like a normal dvd". 'play' and 'normal DVD' suggest DVD video to me.